# rails - given a column already in the prod DB - How to add a migration that adds a Default Val

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a column version_num, in one of my tables, i just noticed that by default the value is not populating to 1.

Given that I already have the field in production, how can you add a migration that just adds a default value to the field?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `change_column` method:

```
change_column :some_table, :column, :type, :default => 'foo'
```

See also: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Comment: not working with rails 3.0.9? i get `undefined method 'type=' for nil:NilClass`